# How do I set an environment variable for a certain command?

Tags: environment-variables

For example, I must set `https_proxy` when using `aws` but not in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.bashrc` you can write, for example

```
alias aws="https_proxy=YOURPROXY aws"
```